# when i use HashMap in java all my values get overrided

Tags: java, arraylist, put

if this is my hashmap

```
HashMap<String,ArrayList<Objects>> a;
```

if the first key is "dog" and the value is an arraylist called object1.
if i add another key called "cat" and the value is an arraylist called object2. Then the object 2 arraylist overrides the they key with dog so its value is also object 2. How do I fix this?

This is what I am doing:

```
keywordsIndex.put("dog", object1);
keywordsIndex.put("cat", object2);
```

I am getting this basically:

[dog=object2, cat=object2]

when i want this:

[dog=object1, cat=object2]

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Post your relevant code in-method. Make sure you compile after cleaning the project.

Comment: Please provide the relevant code to reproduce your issue.

Comment: You are probably using the same arraylist in both cases...

Answer (score 0):

Please share your code, we can only guess otherwise.

As per my guess, Look like your dog and cat pointing to same object or are equal (same hashcode and equals), so when you're setting cat=object2 it's  overriding the first key.

Just to test use below order:-
keywordsIndex.put("cat", object2);
keywordsIndex.put("dog", object1);

and check the value or check what is the map size after adding second element.